# How do you modify an object in an array and then return a new version of that array?

Tags: javascript

I'm modifying the property of an object inside an array in the following way:

```
const newPanoramas = state.panoramas.map(panorama => {
  if (state.panorama.id === panorama.id) {
    panorama.thumbnail = thumbnail
  }
})
```

I know I have to return something---but I'm not very sure what ...

Comment: you actually modify the original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the most important part: to *return* the mapped object. Should be :

```
const newPanoramas = state.panoramas.map(panorama => {
  if (state.panorama.id === panorama.id) {
    panorama.thumbnail = thumbnail
  }
  return panorama;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to return is the object you modified

```
const newPanoramas = state.panoramas.map(panorama => {
  if (state.panorama.id === panorama.id) {
    panorama.thumbnail = thumbnail
  }
return panorama;
})
```

That object will be returned an stored in newPanorama.